# Flutter Provider Error: The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: flutter: _HomePageState#fb424):

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

My code was actually working and is currently working with the app built from the previous version of flutter. I built it again using the same code but with the Flutter 1.22 upgrade and its causing error now on Provider. Since, the code actually worked, I can't seem to figure out why it is throwing an error.

Here is my code:

The file or the error causing widget according to flutter:
'''

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String id = 'home_page';
  final String currentUserId;
  HomePage({this.currentUserId});
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

CategoryProvider categoryProvider;
ProductProvider productProvider;

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
// variables
  double height, width;
  bool homeColor = true;
  bool checkoutColor = false;
  bool aboutColor = false;
  bool contactUsColor = false;
  bool profileColor = false;
  MediaQueryData mediaQuery;
  TextEditingController searchTextEditingController = TextEditingController();

  //category each tile change to Service

  Widget _buildCategoryProduct({String name, String image, int color}) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),

            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: shadowList,
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            // maxRadius: height * 0.1 / 2.1,
            // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: Image(
              image:

                  /// changed
                  AssetImage('images/category/$image'),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            name,
            style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              letterSpacing: 1.0,
              textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

// firebase auth drawer details
  /// look into it after
  Widget _buildUserAccountsDrawerHeader() {
    List<UserModel> userModel = productProvider.userModelList;
    return Column(
        children: userModel.map((e) {
      return UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        accountName: Text(
          e.userName,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundImage: e.userImage == null
              ? AssetImage("images/userImage.png")
              : NetworkImage(e.userImage),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xfff2f2f2)),
        accountEmail: Text(e.userEmail, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      );
    }).toList());
  }

//build drawer left side/sidebar
  Widget _buildMyDrawer() {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildUserAccountsDrawerHeader(),
          ListTile(
            selected: homeColor,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                homeColor = true;
                contactUsColor = false;
                checkoutColor = false;
                aboutColor = false;
                profileColor = false;
              });
            },
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text("Home"),
          ),
          ListTile(
            selected: checkoutColor,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                checkoutColor = true;
                contactUsColor = false;
                homeColor = false;
                profileColor = false;
                aboutColor = false;
              });
              // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => CheckOut()));
            },
            leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            title: Text("Checkout"),
          ),
          ListTile(
            selected: aboutColor,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                aboutColor = true;
                contactUsColor = false;
                homeColor = false;
                profileColor = false;
                checkoutColor = false;
              });
              //  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              //      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => About()));
            },
            leading: Icon(Icons.info),
            title: Text("About"),
          ),
          ListTile(
            selected: profileColor,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                aboutColor = false;
                contactUsColor = false;
                homeColor = false;
                profileColor = true;
                checkoutColor = false;
              });
              // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              // MaterialPageRoute(
              //   builder: (ctx) => ProfileScreen(),
              //  ),
              // );
            },
            leading: Icon(Icons.info),
            title: Text("Profile"),
          ),
          ListTile(
            selected: contactUsColor,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                contactUsColor = true;
                checkoutColor = false;
                profileColor = false;
                homeColor = false;
                aboutColor = false;
              });
              // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => ContactUs()));
            },
            leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
            title: Text("Contant Us"),
          ),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
            },
            leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            title: Text("Logout"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /// carousel on top/ change images ^^finalized
  Widget _buildImageSlider() {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: Carousel(
        borderRadius: true,
        radius: Radius.circular(20),
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayDuration: Duration(seconds: 10),
        showIndicator: false,
        images: [
          // change it up to more approp
          AssetImage('images/banner2.jpg'),
          AssetImage('images/banner1.jpg'),
          AssetImage('images/banner4.jpg'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


 
// build category/services row """"
  Widget _buildCategory() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 40,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "SERVICES",
                style: GoogleFonts.caveat(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  letterSpacing: 3.0,
                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 70,
          // change new
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // each Service icon
                  _buildHairIcon(),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  _buildWaxIcon(),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  _buildPedicureIcon(),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  _buildManicureIcon(),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  _buildFacialIcon(),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  // row of featured and archives view more
  Widget _buildNewAchives() {
    final Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    return Container(
      /// look into it
      height: 500,
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
        childAspectRatio: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 0.8 : 0.9,
        children: productProvider.getHomeAchiveList.map((e) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (ctx) => DetailScreen(
                    userId: widget.currentUserId,
                    hairdresserId: e.id,
                    image: e.image,
                    rating: e.rating,
                    name: e.name,
                    surname: e.surname,
                    description: e.description,
                    city: e.city,
                    waxPrice: e.waxPrice,
                    facialPrice: e.facialPrice,
                    manicurePrice: e.manicurePrice,
                    pedicurePrice: e.pedicurePrice,
                    hairPrice: e.hairPrice,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: SingleProduct(
                image: e.image, rating: e.rating, name: e.name, city: e.city),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

// row of featured and archives view more
  Widget _buildRow() {
    List<Product> newAchivesProduct = productProvider.getNewAchiesList;
    return Container(
      height: height * 0.1 - 30,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "FEATURED ",
                style: GoogleFonts.caveat(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  letterSpacing: 3.0,
                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (ctx) => ListProduct(
                        userId: widget.currentUserId,
                        name: "Featured",
                        isCategory: false,
                        snapShot: newAchivesProduct,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Text(
                  "View all",
                  style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  // to get from online firebase database//change names
  void getCallAllFunction() {
    categoryProvider.getWaxData();
    categoryProvider.getHairData();
    categoryProvider.getPedicureData();
    categoryProvider.getManicureData();
    categoryProvider.getFacialData();
    categoryProvider.getHairIconData();
    productProvider.getNewAchiveData();
    productProvider.getFeatureData();
    productProvider.getHomeFeatureData();
    productProvider.getHomeAchiveData();
    categoryProvider.getWaxIcon();
    categoryProvider.getPedicureIconData();
    categoryProvider.getManicureIconData();
    categoryProvider.getFacialIconData();
    // productProvider.getUserData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //from models product= hairdresser data

    categoryProvider = Provider.of<CategoryProvider>(context);
    productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);
    final String currentUserId = Provider.of<UserData>(context).currentUserId;
    getCallAllFunction();
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      drawer: _buildMyDrawer(),
      // bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarOpacity: 0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
        // search field
        title: Text(
          'The Mob',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: 'Billabong',
            fontSize: 35.0,
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset("images/menu.svg"),
          onPressed: () {
            _key.currentState.openDrawer();
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          NotificationButton(),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 5),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _buildImageSlider(),
                  _buildCategory(),
                  _buildRow(),
                  _buildNewAchives(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

'''

I have provided the multi providers in the main while with child as MaterialApp. Hence the main file looks like this:

'''

```
  void main() async {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
     await Firebase.initializeApp();
     runApp(
       MultiProvider(
         providers: [
           ChangeNotifierProvider(
             create: (context) => ServicesNotifier(),
           ),
           ChangeNotifierProvider(
             create: (context) => HairdresserData(),
           ),
           ChangeNotifierProvider(
             create: (context) => ServicesNotifier(),
           ),
           ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoryProvider>(
             create: (context) => CategoryProvider(),
           ),
           ChangeNotifierProvider<ProductProvider>(
             create: (context) => ProductProvider(),
           ),
           ChangeNotifierProvider(
             create: (context) => UserData(),
           ),
         ],
         child: MyApp(),
       ),
     );
   }
   '''
   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     // This widget is the root of your application.
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         home: OnboardingScreen(),
         routes: {
           //  '/a': (_) => Authenticate(),
           SignInScreen.id: (context) => SignInScreen(),
           RegisterScreen.id: (context) => RegisterScreen(),
           LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
           SignupScreen.id: (context) => SignupScreen(),
           '/b': (_) => Customer(),
           '/c': (_) => Hairdresser(),
           '/d': (_) => Choose(),
           '/e': (_) => IndicatorScreen(),
         },
       );
     }
   }
```

The error is as follows:

````
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state:
flutter: _HomePageState#fb424):
flutter: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<CategoryProvider> above this HomePage Widget
flutter:
flutter: This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
flutter: of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
flutter:
flutter: - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
flutter:
flutter:   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
flutter:   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
flutter:
flutter: - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
flutter:
flutter:   Make sure that HomePage is under your MultiProvider/Provider<CategoryProvider>.
flutter:   This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
flutter:
flutter:   For example, instead of:
flutter:
flutter:   ```
flutter:   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
flutter:     return Provider<Example>(
flutter:       create: (_) => Example(),
flutter:       // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
flutter:       // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
flutter:       child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
flutter:     ),
flutter:   }
flutter:   ```
flutter:
flutter:   consider using `builder` like so:
flutter:   ```
flutter:   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
flutter:     return Provider<Example>(
flutter:       create: (_) => Example(),
flutter:       // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
flutter:       builder: (context) {
flutter:         // No longer throws
flutter:         return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
flutter:       }
flutter:     ),
flutter:   }
flutter:   ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I simply resolve this issue by move all the files to lib instead of making provider directory to lib because provider did not able to find another file that we want to use. It works for me.